# Convert isom to mp42

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, codec, converters

How do I convert a video from ISOM to MP42?
Using FFMPEG in particular? There is no such an option to specify that.

```
General
Complete name                            : C:\wamp\www\tree.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom
File size                                : 763 KiB
Duration                                 : 3s 834ms
Overall bit rate                         : 1 630 Kbps
Writing application                      : Lavf56.30.100
```

Answer (score 8):

MP4Box, part of [GPAC](https://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/downloads/gpac-nightly-builds/), can do this as follows:

```
MP4Box -brand mp42 file.mp4
```